# Unable to connect via connection string to Dynamics CRM Online. Organization cannot be null or empty. Parameter name: Organization Name

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

I'm trying to connect to CRM Online via connection string using `Microsoft.CrmSdk.XrmTooling.CoreAssembly v 8.2.0.5`

Following the guidelines at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt608573.aspx) my connection string looks like this: `AuthType=Office365;Username=jsmith@contoso.onmicrosoft.com; Password=passcode;Url=https://contoso.crm.dynamics.com`

However, I get error an exception of type `System.ArgumentNullException` with Message: **Organization cannot be null or empty.
Parameter name: Organization Name**

Source: **Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector**

```
public void GetClient()
{
    try
        {
            var client = new CrmServiceClient(GetConnectionString());
            Assert.IsTrue(client.IsReady);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }

}
private string GetConnectionString()
{
    try
    {
        var connectionString = default(string);

        try
        {
            connectionString = "AuthType:Office365;Url=https://MyCRM.crm4.dynamics.com; UserName=ATMain@MyOrganization.com;Password=MySecretPasscode;"; 
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
        return connectionString;
    }
    finally
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to connect to CRM Online? Maybe you are connecting to some on-premise instance and simply have wrong authentication type?

Comment: Yes I'm trying to connect to CRM online indeed.

Comment: paste the GetConnectionString function code and the connection string from app.config (with tags, but of course without passwords and logins), I bet you did some simple error

Comment: told you it's simple error. I posted the answer

Comment: Yep, totally missed that pesky colon in there! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
"AuthType:Office365; ..."
```

This should be:

```
"AuthType=Office365; ..."
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to write the connectionstring like this:

```
 <add name="Server=CRM Online, 
organization=contoso, user=someone"
connectionString="Url=https://contoso.crm.dynamics.com;
Username=someone@contoso.onmicrosoft.com; Password=password; authtype=Office365"/> -->
```

[sample to-do](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/jj602970.aspx)

Hope this help!

Comment: Thanks Javier, I have used the same project to connect but still end up with the same error.

Answer (score -1):

you still need to put the org name at the end of the url so it should be someting like this:Url=https://contoso.crm.dynamics.com/contoso;